# Need to keep newlines in pre tags while removing newlines from all other text

Tags: php, string-formatting

I have user-submitted text via form that could have multiple blocks of text in pre tags. I need to remove all newlines, without removing the newlines in the PRE tags, and preserve any other user formatting.

Comment: the user is adding <pre>? is this from a textarea or a WYSIWYG editor like ck ?

Comment: Yes, the user is adding the pre in a textarea ...not a wysiwyg

Comment: i would use CKEditor if the user needs formatting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use conditional subpatterns here. Assuming `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags are *balanced*, following code should work for you:

```
$str = "abc \nfoo\n <pre>123\ndef\nabc\n</pre>qwer\nttt\n bbb";
$p = '~((<pre>)(?(2).*?</pre>)(?:[^\n]*?))*?\n~smi';
$s = preg_replace($p, "$1", $str);
var_dump($s);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(42) "abc foo <pre>123
def
abc
</pre>qwerttt bbb"
```

As you can see `\n` outside `<pre>` and `</pre>` have been removed.

This code searches for 0 or more occurrences of **text between `<pre>` tag in the string and if found then grabs text until `</pre>` tag**. Single iteration of search stops when first `\n` is found and and then it replaces the matched text with first captured group (i.e. text that came before `\n`).

Comment: Simple ...and works ...very nice! My thinking wasn't even close to this type of solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = // whatever

$tokenized_input = explode('<pre>', $input); 
for($i = 0; $i < count($tokenized_input); ++$i) {
  $substrings = split('</pre>', $tokenized_input[$i]);
  if (!empty($substrings)) {
    $substrings[count($substrings) - 1] = str_replace("\n", '', $substrings[count($substrings) - 1]);
  }
  $tokenized_input[$i] = implode('</pre>', $substrings);
}

$output = implode('<pre>', $tokenized_input);
```

Note that I didn't test this.  It also assumes that:
  - Your `<pre>` tags are all lowercase, with no attributes
  - You're trying to remove only newline characters, not `\r\n`

Comment: Thanks Sam ...I tried your code and it seems to work, but I think I am going to use the answer supplied by anubhava since it's a bit less code.